# Change windows keyboard layout from flex application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have 2 TextInput. One must write with EN, another must MN. Is there any solution to in both of their focusIn change windows keyboard layout from flex application(in coding)?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No!

The flashplayer runs your applications in a sandbox. That means no interaction with the operating system from your code whatsoever. The exceptions are:

- If running in browser you can write cookies
- If running as Air application you can write files if the user agrees